# how to find 2 characters using regex?

Tags: regex

what is the regex to split  string `\"asdfgh\"asd` using delimiter `\"`  ?

i am using java.

when using regex `\\\"`, the result is `\` `asdfgh\` `asd`

but I am expecting this result `asdfgh` `asd`

Comment: Depends on programming language. Try `\\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by Washington Guedes which was deleted for some reason and it worked.

the regex should be `\\\\\"`

the result for my case is :  `asdfgh` `asd`

that is what I want. thanks so much